# Querying a relational database through Google DataFlow Transformer

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to implement a `ParDo` Transformer on my Dataflow Pipeline, that basically query a relational database based on the data provided by each element to be processed. I know every attribute in an user defined transformer must be serializable, but to query data to a database, using `jdbc` I need to create a `Connection` that is naturally non serializable object.

Is still possible to do that in the Dataflow Pipeline context?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What if someone answers 'Yes' and someone else answers 'No' which one would you accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You could make your Connection object transient so that its not serialized and create it once per bundle through the `startBundle` method. Once all the elements in the bundle are processed, the connection can be closed through the `finishBundle` method.

```
class MyDoFn extends DoFn<X, Y> {
  private transient Connection jdbc;

  @Setup
  public void setup(Context c) {
    jdbc = // Create connection
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    // query database
  }

  @Teardown
  public void tearDown(Context c) {
    // close connection
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see also the recently added [JDBC connector](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java) in [Apache Beam (incubating)](http://beam.apache.org/).

Comment: Using the JDBC connector in the context of this question is not possible as using it as a source is meant to read a stream of data and therefore, allows providing a query during the initialization.
It is not meant and therefore does not allow to query based on incoming elements from another stream.